# Find site lies in rectangle when we have latitude and longitude of all corners in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-spatial

I am having a table name as T. Suppose 
I have latitude, longitude of all four corners of a rectangle. How can I find which site or records lies in rectangle?

Suppose we have below left, length of the rectangle:

> Latitude: -22.17,21.17,20.17,22.17
>    Longitude: -71.45,72.45,76.50,76.40

Now by using `SDO_UTIL. GETNUMVERTICES (t. SHAPE)` how can I find which site or record lies in this rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `SDO_UTIL.GETNUMVERTICES` to do that, because that gives you the number of vertices in a single shape and nothing more.

You could, however, construct an SDO_GEOMETRY with your ordinates like so:

```
sdo_geometry(
  2003 -- geometry type 2D polygon
, NULL -- or the relevant SRID corresponding to your data
, NULL
, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1)
, sdo_ordinate_array(x, y, x, y, x, y, x, y, x, y) -- fill in ordinates here
)
```

You can then use this geometry as a query window, i.e. with `SDO_INSIDE`, or `SDO_UTILS.RELATE` to find shapes that are inside this polygon.